# gcc stack overflown due to weird optimization

Tags: c, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization

I have some code set up similarly to the example below. This is for an embedded ARM system with limited memory so my stack is only 800 bytes for this thread.

The basic idea is I am getting fault numbers from modules, a value of 0 clears all faults for that module, and a unique number may trigger a specific fault.
The main goal with the way I have the function laid out is to only write the unique number once, and on the same line as the fault itself.
Currently I am working with 91 faults that can be triggered in this way.

```
enum {
    MOD_1, // 0
    MOD_2,
    MOD_3,
    MOD_4,
    MOD_5,
    MOD_6,
    MOD_7,
    // end
    MOD_LAST,
};

extern short mod_fault[7];

struct fault_mess {
    short MOD_1_SOME_FAULT;
    short MOD_1_DIFFERENT_FAULT;
    ... //more mod 1 faults
    short MOD_1_FINAL_FAULT;

    ... //other mod faults

    short MOD_7_SOME_FAULT;
    short MOD_7_DIFFERENT_FAULT;
    ... //more mod 7 faults
    short MOD_7_FINAL_FAULT;    
}
struct fault_mess fault;

void set_mod_fault(void)
{
    short x, tmp, tmp2;

    for (x=0; x < MOD_LAST; x++)      // check all modules
    {
        if (x == MOD_1)
        {
            tmp = mod_fault[x];
            tmp2 = !!tmp;
            if(!tmp2 | tmp == 67) fault.MOD_1_SOME_FAULT = tmp2;
            if(!tmp2 | tmp == 44) fault.MOD_1_DIFFERENT_FAULT = tmp2;
            ...
            if(!tmp2 | tmp == 69) fault.MOD_1_FINAL_FAULT = tmp2;
        }
        
        ... //more else if cases
        
        else if (x == MOD_7)
        {
            tmp = mod_fault[x];
            tmp2 = !!tmp;
            if(!tmp2 | tmp == 52) fault.MOD_7_SOME_FAULT = tmp2;
            if(!tmp2 | tmp == 81) fault.MOD_7_DIFFERENT_FAULT = tmp2;
            ...
            if(!tmp2 | tmp == 17) fault.MOD_7_FINAL_FAULT = tmp2;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I have is the way gcc is generating instructions for this code. (this is compiled for 32bit ARM, v4T, using -O2)

I've stepped through the assembly code generated, and it is pre-calculating the result of each `if(!tmp2 | tmp == 52)` and pushing the value to the stack. It then enters the loop and stores the value of `tmp2` conditionally based on the value from the stack. The values on the stack are 4bytes wide, which amounts to 364 bytes of stack used for this "optimization". If I compile under -O0 there is no excessive stack usage.

So the code is technically correct because if I increase the stack large enough it will run without crashing. But the behavior of the compiler seems un-intuitive, and somewhat buggy.

I can fix the problem by refactoring the code, but I'm curious if this problem is well documented, or if others view this as something that should be fixed.

edit: I tried compiling with "-fstack-usage" which produced a *.su file.
This file indicates that the function requires 16 bytes of stack when compiling under -O0, but it actually takes 960 bytes of stack when compiling with -O2.

Here is a web example. It doesn't perform as badly as my embedded compiler, using only 200 bytes with -O2, (vs 16 with -O0) http://tpcg.io/w3KBdVZ6

Comment: Ok, first things first. The expressions  `!tmp2 | tmp == 52` either using an incorrect operator (`|` instead of `||`) or have a precedence issue.

Comment: Second - this needs an [mcve]. Where is `extern short mod_fault[7];` actually defined? And third - the problem is *most likely* in your code and not in the optimization.

Comment: You seem to have identified exactly what the problem is. The compiler is precomputing the conditionals and this is overflowing the stack. The compiler is working correctly, in this situation I would recommend refactoring your code. Having 91 separate check conditions is a poor design approach itself.

Comment: I really doubt the compiler will store intermediate results on stack.

Comment: If code looks like huge amounts of copy/paste were used to create it, it's probably in need of being cleaned up.

Comment: `pre-calculating the result of each if(!tmp2 | tmp == 52) and pushing the value to the stack.` can you compile with option -S to give us the corresponding assembler editing your question ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes it is possible to reduce a lot the code to have only few lines (some ideas in my answer, may be you have better ones ?)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: But I think in this particular case, `|` has the same effect as `||` would.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, but I am not sure what is the intention here

Comment: @NateEldredge Not exactly.  `|` doesn't short-circut like `||` does.

Comment: @dbush: That makes no difference *in this particular case* as the second operand happens to have no side effects.

Comment: @NateEldredge Still, I wouldn't be surprised if it made a difference in what the optimizer does.

Comment: @dbush: Possible, but [doesn't appear so](https://godbolt.org/z/n48a1P)

Comment: I have tried it using both ```||``` and ```|```.  In either case the stack usage is the same, as indicated by the -fstack-usage compiler option.

Comment: and compiling with `-Os` ?

Answer (score 3):

> it is pre-calculating the result of each if(!tmp2 | tmp == 52) and pushing the value to the stack.

until you edit your question to show us the generated assembler using option `-S` I have a serious doubt on that

> ...amounts to 364 bytes of stack
> if I increase the stack large enough it will run without crashing

even what you say about the pushes is true to have or not 364 more bytes will not explode your stack, the reason is elsewhere and you very probably have **undefined behavior(s)** somewhere

> the code is technically correct

sorry to say but your code is really a mess !

The `struct fault_mess` with it seems 91 fields (`7*('M' - 'A' + 1)`) is a non sense, why are you not using for instance `char fault[MOD_LAST]['M' - 'A' + 1]` allowing to have that first level of simplification :

```
for (x=0; x < MOD_LAST; x++)      // check all modules
{
  if (!mod_fault[x])
  {
    memset(fault[x], 0, sizeof(fault[x]));
  }
  else
  {
    tmp = mod_fault[x];

    switch (x) {
    case MOD_1:
      switch (tmp) {
      case 67: fault[MOD_1]['A'-'A'] = 1; break;
      case 44: fault[MOD_1]['B'-'A'] = 1; break;
      ...
      }
      break;
    ...
    case MOD_7:
      switch (tmp) {
      case 52: fault[MOD_7]['A'-'A'] = 1; break;
      case 81: fault[MOD_7]['B'-'A'] = 1; break;
      ...
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I use an array of `char` for *fault* but you save `bool` (0 or 1)

a second level of simplification can be done defining a constant two dimensional array of `char` whose first dimension is `MOD_LAST` and the second 13 (`'M' - 'A' + 1`) with

```
arr[MOD_1]['A'-'A'] = 67
arr[MOD_1]['B'-'A'] = 44
...
arr[MOD_7]['A'-'A'] = 52
arr[MOD_7]['B'-'A'] = 81
..
```

to just need the short code :

```
for (x=0; x < MOD_LAST; x++)      // check all modules
{
  if (!mod_fault[x])
  {
    memset(fault[x], 0, sizeof(fault[x]));
  }
  else
  {
    short tmp = mod_fault[x];
    short * p = arr[x];

    for (i = 0; i != 'M' - 'A' + 1; ++i)
    {
       if (tmp == p[i])
       {
          fault[x][i] = 1;
          break;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Note if the range of possible values of `mod_fault` is small you can also remove the `for` loop using the constant array of `char [MOD_LAST][max-range]` valuing `0 .. 'M'  - 'A' + 1` or any value out of range to detect the case, then

```
#define MIN_VALUE ??
#define MAX_VALUE ??
#define NOT_INDEX 'Z' 
...
for (x=0; x < MOD_LAST; x++)      // check all modules
{
  if (!mod_fault[x])
  {
    memset(fault[x], 0, sizeof(fault[x]));
  }
  else if ((mod_fault[x] >= MIN_VALUE) && (mod_fault[x] <= MAX_VALUE))
  {
    char index = arr[x][mod_fault[x] - MIN_VALUE];
   
    if (index != NOT_INDEX)
      fault[x][index] = 1;
  }
}
```

with

```
arr[MOD_1][76 - MIN_VALUE] = 0; // A
arr[MOD_1][44 - MIN_VALUE] = 1; // B
...
arr[MOD_7][52 - MIN_VALUE] = 0; // A
arr[MOD_7][81 - MIN_VALUE] = 1; // B
...
```

and other entries valuing `NOT_INDEX`

Comment: the "struct fault_mess" is a much larger structure then I indicated here, and it ties into dozens of other places in the system. the system reacts to those faults and logs them in a proprietary format.  essentially I am saying I can't change the format of the structure. The only thing that is significant about each fault is its exact name.

Comment: I am on an embedded system with limited memory. The stack has exactly 800 bytes. I am working on some clarification, hopefully I can post a repeatable example.

Comment: Your code is quite wasteful for a such a limited system.

Comment: @ZacharyVanderKlippe you lost a lot of memory with you complex code and also using `short` for your fields `MOD_<n>_SOME_FAULT_<X>` when only one bit is enough to save 0 or 1 in the code you give

Comment: I think your very large `struct fault_mess` structure shows a design problem.